# How do I set up mirror margins in R markdown using knitr

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr, margins

I know how to adjust the margins in an r markdown pdf file with the following:

```
---
title: "Model 1 Coefficients"
output: pdf_document
geometry: margin=1in
---
```

But I would like to make it so that the margin sizes switch between even and odd pages so that the inner margin is always 1.25 in and outer is always .25 in.

I was able to find some latex info on this website http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf and it seems like I want to use the twoside option but I'm not sure this is right or even how to call it.  I tried the following:

```
---
title: "Model 1 Coefficients"
output: pdf_document
twoside: inner=1.25in, outer=0.25in
---
```

but that didn't do anything to the margins

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
geometry: asymmetric

output:
    pdf_document:
        number_sections: TRUE
        fig_height: 3
        fig_width: 5

---

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\evensidemargin=0in
\oddsidemargin=0.5in
```