# R markdown word ducument output margins

Tags: r, output, r-markdown, margins

I have a question about setting `rmarkdown`'s *word_document* output **margins**.
I browse lots of information and find the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599293/how-do-i-set-up-mirror-margins-in-r-markdown-using-knitr).
It can use `geometry` to set. However, I just want word output margins to become extremely small. I also find [this](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) to set margins.
However, it didn't work.

```
---
title: "Set Margins"
output: word_document
geometry: margins: left = 0.1 cm
                   right = 0.1 cm 
---
```

How to figure out?

Comment: I believe `geometry` is a LATEX package and will only work if you are knitting it to PDF. just use the view ruler in Microsoft word to custom your margins the way you want

Comment: Not all of pandoc's options are available via `rmarkdown` (and the second reference you give is a Latex package, certainly different again!). But you can use [a style reference as explained here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html#style_reference).

Answer (score 3):

With a word document you have previously generated with R markdown name it `margin_styles.docx` and adjust the margins within that document to suit the desired output. Then include the following in the yaml section of the rmarkdown (.Rmd) file:

```
---
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: margin_styles.docx
---
```

The rendered file should have the margins set in `margin_styles.docx`.

See the style reference section of the rmarkdown docs for more detail http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html#style_reference